# UILabel under a custom tableview cell is not getting updated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My **tableview cell is not getting updated** on `viewDidAppear :`

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [[ApiAccess getSharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
    [[[SocektAccess getSharedInstance]getSocket]setDelegate:self];
    [[[SocektAccess getSharedInstance]getSocket] reconnect];
    _chatSocket =[[SocektAccess getSharedInstance]getSocket];


    if(self.updateWill)
    {
        NSLog(@"viewDidAppear");
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.updateId inSection:0];

        NSLog(@"Update Value: %d",self.updateValue);
        NSLog(@"Update ID: %d",self.updateId);



        TimelineTableViewCell *cell = (TimelineTableViewCell *)[self.tableData cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


        WallPost *data = self.myObject[indexPath.row];
        data.commentCount = self.updateValue;

        [self.myObject replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:data];

        WallPost *data2 = self.myObject[indexPath.row];

        NSLog(@": %d",data2.commentCount);


       cell.commentLabel.text = @" ";



        [self.tableData beginUpdates];
        [self.tableData reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [self.tableData reloadData];
        [self.tableData endUpdates];

    }

    self.updateWill = NO;
}
```

The `self.updateWill` is a boolean and has been triggered from another class :

```
if(self.responseAdd.responseStat.status)
        {
            self.commentTxt.text=@"";
            [self getData];
            TimelineViewController *t = (TimelineViewController *)self.navigationController.viewControllers[0];
            t.updateWill = YES;
            t.updateId = self.index;
            t.updateValue =(int)self.response.responseData.count+1;
            NSLog(@"response %d",(int)self.response.responseData.count);

        }
```

as you can see i have created a object of my Main class which is **TimelineViewController** and has added the value of updateWill and other needed properties. But the cell is not getting reloaded!! w**hats i am doing wrong in here ??**

**update**

```
(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    TimelineTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.counter = 0;

    WallPost *data = self.myObject[indexPath.row];

    cell.image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    cell.image.tag = indexPath.row;

    if(self.updateWill == YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"YES YES");
       data.commentCount= (int)self.updateValue;



         [self.tableData beginUpdates];
         [self.tableData reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
         [self.tableData reloadData];
         [self.tableData endUpdates];
         cell.commentLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d comments",data.commentCount];


    }
    else
    {
        data.commentCount = (int)data.comments.count;
        cell.commentLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d comments",data.commentCount];

    }
```

Comment: Actually, the thing is that you need to do the update stuff inside the cellforrowindex method of tableview Delegate rather than lifecycle methods of view. So, make sure you are doing the same.

Comment: i tried that too yet it didn't work!!! @Himanshu

Comment: Update your cellforrowindex code may be there is something wrong there.

Comment: tried to do the same thing in cellForRowIndex @Himanshu

Comment: okay so clean your this code from your viewdidload and in viewdidappear write  self.tableView.reloadData()

Comment: I have achieved the same but in swift, let me try if I can give you in objc, btw **you need to reload table and get visible cell then update particular cell in viewDidAppear method**.

Comment: where do u want me to write that @Himanshu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need to workaround in **objective c**

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

[self.tableData reloadData];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    //Background Thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Run UI Updates
     NSArray *paths = [self.tableData indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    for (NSIndexPath *path in paths) 
    {
          //get desired cell here
          CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[(UITableView *)self.view cellForRowAtIndexPath: path 
];

         cell.labeView //now you can update here on your cell items
      }

    });
});
}
```

and this is my original logic in **Swift**

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)


        tableView.reloadData()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

            //get visible cells indexpaths
            if let indices = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows
            {
                for index in indices
                {
                    if index.section == 0 //this is specific to me, checking if section 0 is visible
                    {
                        //get desired cell here
                        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0,inSection: 0)) as! CustomCell

                        cell.myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true //now i can update imageview on table cell

                    }
                }
            }

        })

    }
```

Comment: after tuning it a bit according to my code it actually worked :)

Comment: @Fay007 I am glad that it helps you ;)

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad

```
[self.tableData reloadData];
```

I hope it will be useful.

Comment: why it's needed in viewDidLoad